# Django generic view is not accepting arguments

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I am just trying to pass arguments to Django generic base View and it is not showing up in terminal as I am printing the arguments passed.

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import View
class CartView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        item = request.GET.get('item')
        qty = request.GET.get('qty')
        print item, qty
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$', 'newsletter.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', 'newsletter.views.contact', name='contact'),
    url(r'^about/$', 'dressika.views.about', name='about'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('products.urls')),
    url(r'^categories/', include('products.urls_categories')),
    url(r'^cart/', CartView.as_view(), name='cart'),
```

When I add some data in browser like `"localhost:8000/cart/?item=2&qty=5"` it is not showing the arguments in terminal according to above code. By only typing `"localhost:8000/cart/"` it does redirects me to homepage. But with arguments it shows 404.

Comment: Try : request.GET['item']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may have to fix the entry in urls.py routing to the view. Could you post your urls.py as well?

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: Sorry might be better as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation. To clarify - I'm pretty sure it is an issue with urls.py due to the 404, but can't know for sure without seeing the urls.py.

Comment: I understood your point....actually when I moved my "cart" url under accounts it worked. What's the logic in it? My urls.py is posted in my question. How to order entries in urls.py and based on what?

Comment: I'm not sure how you changed your url.  The first url that matches will be the  one used.  By not specifying $ at the end or cart/ you are allowing further url info to go the the view as HttpRequest.GET¶

Comment: Yeah I got it now. But the question remains that in case of multiple apps what should be the order to list urls.